# Border-top display

Tags: rules

I need to display border on the very top of a page and I can't figure out how to do that. If it helps in CSS it would be: border-top: 5px solid blue; Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another possibiltity is with `background` package.

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{background}

\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
angle=0,
contents={
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw [magenta,line width = 5pt] (current page.north west) -- (current page.north east);}
  }

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-50]
\end{document}
```

[image]

At close-up:

[image]

You may change the width of the line, color etc in `\draw [magenta,line width = 5pt]...`
angle, scaling etc may be controlled within the options for `\backgroundsetup{...}`. For details, `texdoc background` or visit [www.texdoc.net](http://www.texdoc.net).

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I had to modify it a bit, because of reasons to me unknown when I compile your code on my computer the line draws in the middle of the page

Comment: @Joe You have to compile at least 2-3 times to get things properly.

Comment: Please note that the `line width` must be twice the desired width since the half of it lays out of the page. On can also use the `calc` library and specify the coordinates like this `($(current page.north west)-(0,\pgflinewidth/2)$)`.

Answer (score 4):

**(1: red border)** You can use TikZ and the absolute page anchors to draw the border and the [`everyshi`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/everyshi) package to add it on each page.

```
\EveryShipout{%
   \tikz[remember picture,overlay]
      \draw [draw=red,line width=10pt]% only half of the line will
                                      % be visible on the page
         (current page.north west) -- (current page.north east);
}
```

**(2: blue border)** If you want to add the border only on regular text pages for instance you can use the page header to add the line. An example using [`scrpage2`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrpage2), for instance:

```
\chead[]{
   \tikz[remember picture,overlay]
      \draw [blue,line width=10pt]% only half of the line will
                                      % be visible on the page
         (current page.south west) -- (current page.south east);
}
```

Where the empty optional arguments causes chapter start pages and empty pages to not have the line.

**(3: green border)** To add a line on chapter-start pages only one can hack into the chapter font in KOMA-Script (or create a new chapter page header style, or use [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec)):

```
\addtokomafont{chapter}{%
   \tikz[remember picture,overlay]
      \draw [draw=green,line width=70pt]% only half of the line will
                                      % be visible on the page
         (current page.north west) -- (current page.south west);
}
```

[image: example image]

**full MWE** showing all three approaches:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz}% for (1) to (3)
\usepackage{everyshi}% only for (1)
\usepackage{scrpage2}% only for (2)
\usepackage{lipsum}% blind text for demonstration

% (1) add the top border at every page
\EveryShipout{%
   \tikz[remember picture,overlay]
      \draw [draw=red,line width=70pt]% only half of the line will
                                      % be visible on the page
         (current page.north west) -- (current page.north east);
}

% (2) add a bottom margin only on regular text pages, i.e. not
% on chapter-start pages or empty pages
\chead[]{
   \tikz[remember picture,overlay]
      \draw [blue,line width=70pt]% only half of the line will
                                      % be visible on the page
         (current page.south west) -- (current page.south east);
}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

% (3) add a border on chapter-start pages only
\addtokomafont{chapter}{%
   \tikz[remember picture,overlay]
      \draw [draw=green,line width=70pt]% only half of the line will
                                      % be visible on the page
         (current page.north west) -- (current page.south west);
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum[1-12]
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Like all TikZ pictures, using the `remember picture,overlay` setup, this must be compiled at least twice to get the right results.