# Error after exiting pdf in Texmaker and SumatraPdf

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, pdf, texmaker, backgrounds

After compiling the document below:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\edpeercopyright}[2]{%
      {\small\color{black}Copyright \copyright\ 2013 edpeer.org \textregistered. Unauthorized photocopying is prohibited.}\quad{\color{#1}\rule{#2}{3pt}}%
    }
\backgroundsetup{%
                contents={\edpeercopyright{red}{5cm}},
                angle=90,
                position={-1.5,-5},%
                opacity=1,
                scale=1
                }
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

I get the following error upon exiting the pdf file generated:

```
! .\mupdf\source\pdf\pdf-interpret.c:2542: cannot find extgstate resource 'pgf@CA1' ! .\mupdf\source\pdf\pdf-interpret.c:2825: cannot set graphics state - .\mupdf\source\pdf\pdf-interpret.c:3044: Ignoring errors during rendering ! .\mupdf\source\pdf\pdf-interpret.c:2542: cannot find extgstate resource 'pgf@ca1' ! .\mupdf\source\pdf\pdf-interpret.c:2825: cannot set graphics state ! .\mupdf\source\pdf\pdf-interpret.c:2542: cannot find extgstate resource 'pgf@CA1' ! .\mupdf\source\pdf\pdf-interpret.c:2825: cannot set graphics state ! .\mupdf\source\pdf\pdf-interpret.c:2542: cannot find extgstate resource 'pgf@ca1' ! .\mupdf\source\pdf\pdf-interpret.c:2825: cannot set graphics state ! .\mupdf\source\pdf\pdf-interpret.c:2542: cannot find extgstate resource 'pgf@CA1' ! .\mupdf\source\pdf\pdf-interpret.c:2825: cannot set graphics state - .\mupdf\source\pdf\pdf-interpret.c:3044: Ignoring errors during rendering ! .\mupdf\source\pdf\pdf-interpret.c:2542: cannot find extgstate resource 'pgf@ca1' ! .\mupdf\source\pdf\pdf-interpret.c:2825: cannot set graphics state ! .\mupdf\source\pdf\pdf-interpret.c:2542: cannot find extgstate resource 'pgf@CA1' ! .\mupdf\source\pdf\pdf-interpret.c:2825: cannot set graphics state ! .\mupdf\source\pdf\pdf-interpret.c:2542: cannot find extgstate resource 'pgf@ca1' ! .\mupdf\source\pdf\pdf-interpret.c:2825: cannot set graphics state
```

Why is this? Something tells me its the command `\edpeercopyright`.

Comment: It renders well in TeXmaker Integrated PDFviewer of why not use it ? Are you with Sumatrapdf 2.4 latest

Comment: @texenthusiast Yes am using the latest versions of both texmaker and sumatrapdf.

Comment: does this happen with a super minimal document, or just with all the stuff you have now

Comment: @MrKomandez http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130388/10898 This compiles well, though.

Comment: i don't get an error when I compile and open then close in sumatrapdf.  where is this error being displayed?

Comment: No problem on TexnicCenter 2, sumatrapdf2.4

Answer (score 5):

The pdf produced is buggy: It references an ExtGState `pgf@CA1`, but does not define it.

Please report the bug to the authors of the `background` package, although I suspect a bug in `pgf`.

Comment: It seems ok to me in `pgfsys-common-pdf.def` file. How do you check if it is buggy? (Out of curiosity)

Comment: @percusse: `qpdf -qdf` and look at the pdf. The content stream of the page references the ExtGState `pgf@CA1`, but the `/ExtGState` dict in the `/Resources` is empty.

Comment: Does it have the same when you use `opacity=0.5,` ? I can't get my head around this yet.

Comment: @percusse: Yes. Make sure that `\pgfutil@addpdfresource@extgs` has the right definition and is eventually called at the right place. You can debug this with `\pdfcompresslevel0`.

Comment: I will surely submit the report if you have not done it.